# Change the parent of the parent of the script from Workspace to you by a script Roblox.Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

So i recently made a car in my roblox game in which i made a tool which can put a light on the top of the car (with an emote) but now i want the Tool to be visible only when a player is in the car, and remove it when he steps out. So i made a variable which checks the name of the player that's currently sitting, i printed this variable and its my name, which is good, but when i made the Parent of the Parent this variable (the player's name) it didn't work.. I tried replacing it with my roblox name (which is exactly the same as the variable) this DID work. So now my question is: How can i still do this, while doing it with a variable (if this is possible)?

The script is here:

- this is not a LocalScript, it is a normal script.

```
    if Seat.Occupant == nil then
        script.Parent.Parent = workspace
    end
    if Seat.Occupant ~= nil then
        GP.Name = Seat.Occupant.Name
        script.Parent.Parent = GP.(the variable, which is the person sitting).Backpack
    end
```

GP is just `game.players`, since this was easier for me :')

And an extra question is how i can make the tool work the second time, since when i use the tool, step out, step in again, it doesn't work anymore.. Atleast, the Light doesn't disappear, the emote is still triggered, which i find weird.
I tried so much, but it doesn't work, so if anyone knows the solution, please let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Is it a localscript or script? Also, `<code> GP.Name = Seat.Occupant.Name </code>`  makes no sense,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Seat.Occupant` returns the `Humanoid` of the character, so referencing the parent of that gives you the character. This puts the tool in the character, equipping it, which is more likely what you want if you want this to be accessible only while in a vehicle.

Although, I have no idea what the object `GP` is in here.

```lua
if Seat.Occupant == nil then
    script.Parent.Parent = workspace
else
    GP.Name = Seat.Occupant.Name
    script.Parent.Parent = Seat.Occupant.Parent
end
```